# Prevent column elements from wrapping

Tags: html, css

I have 3 columns but the columns split up and restart at the top.

[image]

(I marked the relevant divs red)

CSS

```
.block
{
    background-color:white;
    width:330px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    display:block;
}

#content
{
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count:3;
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

How can I make it so the divs don't split up?

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/kmaezfbp/1/)

Comment: Please show us an example in jsfiddle

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/break-inside

Comment: These columns are good for text but not for divs. Maybe it's worth to use float divs or JQuery masonry plugin instead.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Fixed by adding `display:inline-block` to .block.

```css
body {
  background-color: #EAEDF4;
  overflow-x: hidden;
}
#content {
  -moz-column-count: 3;
  -webkit-column-count: 3;
  column-count: 3;
  display: block;
  margin-top: 50px;
}
.block {
  background-color: white;
  width: 330px;
  margin-bottom: 25px;
  display: inline-block;
}
.green {
  background: lightgreen;
  height: 400px;
}
.blue {
  background: lightblue;
  height: 500px;
}
.yellow {
  background: lightyellow;
  height: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="content">
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
  <div class="block yellow"></div>
  <div class="block green"></div>
  <div class="block yellow"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block yellow"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
  <div class="block blue"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry I stomped on your edit. I'll get out of the way now.

Answer (score 1):

you can try this one:

```
body {
    background-color:#EAEDF4;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.block {
    background-color:white;
    width:330px;
    margin-bottom:25px;
    display:inline-block;
}
#content {
    -moz-column-count: 3;
    -webkit-column-count: 3;
    column-count:3;
    display:block;
    margin-top:50px;
}
```

[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/kmaezfbp/5/)